# define hbm out of dll

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I need to generate hbm int the real time. therefore I need to define hbm files out of dll . And dll must contain reference to this xml files. 
If this possible in NHibernate??
Or may be reference to properties .
thanks

Comment: Maybe you should look into Fluent Nhibernate instead? http://fluentnhibernate.org/

Comment: @jishi if he needs to generate the hbm in "real time", Fluent is definitely NOT an option.

Comment: Agree, but I found it to be an odd request so I was guessing he maybe expressed himself poorly.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. NHibernate can load hbms out of pretty much anywhere:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public Configuration AddAssembly(Assembly assembly);
    public Configuration AddAssembly(string assemblyName);
    public Configuration AddClass(Type persistentClass);
    public void AddDeserializedMapping(HbmMapping mappingDocument,
                                       string documentFileName);
    public Configuration AddDirectory(DirectoryInfo dir);
    public Configuration AddDocument(XmlDocument doc);
    public Configuration AddDocument(XmlDocument doc, string name);
    public Configuration AddFile(FileInfo xmlFile);
    public Configuration AddFile(string xmlFile);
    public Configuration AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream);
    public Configuration AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, string name);
    public Configuration AddResource(string path, Assembly assembly);
    public Configuration AddResources(IEnumerable<string> paths,
                                      Assembly assembly);
    public Configuration AddUrl(string url);
    public Configuration AddUrl(Uri url);
    public Configuration AddXml(string xml);
    public Configuration AddXml(string xml, string name);
    public Configuration AddXmlFile(string xmlFile);
    public Configuration AddXmlReader(XmlReader hbmReader);
    public Configuration AddXmlReader(XmlReader hbmReader, string name);
    public Configuration AddXmlString(string xml);
}
```